# Maven-ear-plugin custom finalname

Tags: java, xml, maven, ear

I can't find a solution to my problem.
in short: in the ear/pom.xml with this configuration all work perfectly

```
<project ...>
  <build>
     <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
     ....
  </build>
</project>
```

But when i try to add a timestamp to finalname:

```
...
<finalName>${project.artifactId}-${maven.build.timestamp}</finalName>
...
```

I get this error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-ear-plugin:2.8:generate-application-xml
>   (default-generate-application-xml) on project soc-ear: Unable to copy
>   application.xml to final destination: The file, directory, or volume
>   name syntax is incorrect

Some idea? Thanks in advance

Comment: A simple solution is to not change the ear file name in each build. The timestamp will be created at file create time, and if you need additional info, use the Maven resource plugin to populate a build properties file with each build, and include the project version and timestamp there. If you absolutely must change the ear filename, modify the bundleFileName element in the ear plugin configuration rather than the project final name. See http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/ear-mojo.html

Comment: The finalName tag is only for the filename in the target folder but will not influence the name of the resulting name which is installed via `mvn install` or the one which is deployed to remote repositories via `mvn deploy`....

Comment: With bundleFileName i can't change ear name, but only module names. I need to change the final name of ear

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution.
To edit the final name, just move the property to the plugin

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${maven.build.timestamp}</finalName>
                    ...
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I do not know the difference between putting it in the generic build rather than in the plugin, but it does work.